# Confusing parameter for cloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-neptune

Hello i am planning to run the cloudFormation stack that is preconfigured by aws [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started-cfn-lambda.html).
It prompts me to fill out

- NeptuneBulkloadIAMRoleArn
- NeptuneClusterEndpoint
- NeptuneLambdaIAMRoleArn

But i don't know what to fill in there, can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters you described above are used for the following:

- NeptuneBulkloadIAMRoleArn - This is an IAM role setup to run the [loader command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-load.html). Instructions for setting this up found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-IAM.html).
- NeptuneClusterEndpoint - This is the endpoint of your Neptune database, it will be accessible either from the console or the CLI.
- NeptuneLambdaIAMRoleArn - This allows you to pass in your own role the Lambda should use, if not specified the CloudFormation stack should make one for you.